# MySQL Workbench Model Diagram Icons not displaying

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL workbench for a class on MacOS with the M1 chip and I really don't know the first thing about it yet. However when I open up a new model and diagram none of the icons or search bar appear. Any help on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

[image]

I have tried playing around with the settings, as well as downloading the application again, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: This isn't a question about MySQL. It's a question about whatever tool you're using to create Entity-Relationship Diagrams.

Comment: Meaning? To my knowledge MySQL is the only tool I am using, like I said I have to use it for a class. I am in no way knowledgeable on the subject

Comment: MySQL is a database, it's not a user application. I guess that's MySQL Workbench.

Comment: What icons are missing? I see icons next to each table column. And there's a Search field in the top right.

Comment: The icons on the left to create new tables, relationships, etc. I can hover over them and use them, but cannot see them. Same issue with the search bar as well as whatever I type in.

Comment: And it is workbench

Comment: I've never used Workbench, I can't help with this.

Comment: Unbelieveable Barmar, please tell me you aren't mysqld to do everything?

Comment: You need to raise this with mysql support as a bug. There is nothong we can do to fix an application for you.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. After upgrade to latest Mac OS version the previous version of MySQL Workbench crashed on opening the model file. Upgrade to 36 version helped but the toolbar is missing. Looking at the crash log it even was related to the toolbar. The new version prevents the crash but the toolbar is not showing the icons.

However you can still click on them but you must guess where you icon is and know what you need. Use the shortcuts for now:

```
L - Layer 
T - Table
V - View
D - Delete
G - Routines
H - Hand
I - Image
N - Text
1,2,3,4,5 are the various link types
```

I found a picture here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-vertical-toolbar.html

It is a workaround but at least something that let one continue working.

Comment: You're a life saver :-D!